# Javascript object containing array of comma separated coordinates

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What's the correct format for an object containing an array of comma separated numbers?
Here is what I am doing, but I am unsure if it is the correct way:

```
var myObj = {

    'coord1' : { 'section-a' : [216,259,216,294,165,294,165,259,216,259] },

    'coord2' : { 'section-a' : [20,218,8,178,3,143,6,112,13] }
};
```

I'd like to access the coordinates of a section by the following:

```
for(var coord in myObj){
    for(var section in coord){
        alert(section);
    }
}
```

And have the raw coordinates returned as a comma separated string.  Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no "right way". It depends on the situation and what makes sense. However, you shouldn't use `for..in` without including using `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @MattBurland Sure you should, it adds unnecessary processing

Comment: @Ian: It's not unnecessary processing, it's accepted best practice. Try reading "Javascript, the good parts". It's highly recommended. It's also recommended by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Ffor...in)

Comment: @MattBurland I don't see anywhere on MDN that says "You should **always** use `hasOwnProperty`. There's examples without it, showing it works fine. You should only use `hasOwnProperty` if necessary. Oh, so we must all follow "JavaScript, the Good Parts"? I don't understand what the "best practice" is here...

Comment: @Ian: `If you only want to consider properties attached to the object itself, and not its prototypes, use getOwnPropertyNames or perform a hasOwnProperty check`. Not `maybe you should think about it`, `use`.

Comment: @MattBurland That's fine you think that, but it still doesn't make sense for an `Object` instance. Maybe for custom objects, but the `Object` prototype shouldn't be modified, so you shouldn't blindly use `hasOwnProperty`. Modifying `Object.prototype` modifies everything's `prototype` since they all inherit from `Object`. If you want to iterate an `Object` and **need** to be safe, iterate through `Object.keys(obj)` in a normal `for`.

Comment: @Ian: You are still missing the point. No, you shouldn't modify `Object.prototype`, but you can stop *every other programmer in the world from doing it*. And for that reason, you should program defensively. If an extra `hasOwnProperty` is going cripple your script, then you have bigger problems.

Comment: @MattBurland What's stopping another programmer from modifying `hasOwnProperty`? A programmer can modify (almost) whatever they want...so why focus on **only** `hasOwnProperty`. I'd rather not waste time and processing shouldn't be needed. This conversation is full of "should"s

Comment: @MattBurland http://jsfiddle.net/jzJEu/ - what do we do now? You expect us to use `hasOwnProperty` in normal `for` loops too? Or check **every** time you want to access a property/method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately [for in loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) don't do quite what you're expecting.

The variable that you create is property name of the current iteraton when you iterate over an object.  It is the index of the array when you iterate over an array.

```
for(var prop in myObj){
    for(var i in myObj[prop]){
        alert(myObj[prop][i]);
    }
}
```

Note, when iterating over objects you may only want to iterate on direct properties of that object, not properties up the protype chain.  Use [hasOwnPrototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) if you only want to iterate over direct properties on the object.

```
for(var prop in myObj){
    if(myObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        for(var i in myObj[prop]){
            if(myObj[prop].hasOwnProeprty(i)) {
                alert(myObj[prop][i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks!  I'm used to php and guess I was thinking in foreach terms.

Comment: For in loops should always include a .hasOwnProperty check in javascript as good practice.

Comment: @BIOS No they shouldn't. If you're iterating an `Object`, there shouldn't be a reason to use `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @Ian: Yes there is. Code can change `Object.prototype` and add properties to it. Properties that **will** be iterated by `for...in`. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/guRPK/) a quick fiddle.

Comment: @MattBurland If you're using code that modifies **`Object`**'s prototype, you shouldn't be using it. That's what `Object.defineProperty` is for - to make properties not enumerable

Comment: @Ian: Well maybe you never use code that is produced by other people, or maybe nobody else ever uses your code. Good for you. In the real world we have to deal with the *fact* that we don't always know what somebody else's code is going to do.

Comment: @MattBurland That's even worse. If you're using someone else's code, you should know what it does. Your could shouldn't suffer because you don't know how to read documentation or look at code. I use plenty of third-party code, and I've never had to use `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: @MattBurland I've never developed code that's distributed, and it doesn't matter, because I've never, and would never, do something that causes the need for `hasOwnProperty` when iterating an `Object`

Comment: @Ian It doesn't matter because you wouldn't do it? I fail to see how that logic applies to the rest of us.

Comment: @BIOS You should read the other comments, that's not what I said

Comment: @Ian I'm referring to your statement: 'it doesn't matter, because I've never, and would never, do something that causes the need for hasOwnProperty'

Comment: @BIOS Again, you should read the comments. That was simply a reply about others using my code

Comment: I've read the comments thank you. The thread also mentions using other peoples code where Object has been modified directly and to which you gave that completely illogical response, but hey, keep patronising.

Comment: @Ian: Yeah you keep missing the point and handing out terrible advice that is the reason why JavaScript has a terrible reputation in some parts. It doesn't matter that you don't modify `Object.prototype` (and you really shouldn't), if *any* code that is loaded in the browser at the same time as your code does, your code could very well break. That's the point.

Comment: @MattBurland Nah, I'm not missing the point or handing out terrible advice. The reason JavaScript has a bad reputation is because people blindly suggest things without reason, don't understand what's actually happening, and don't care to learn. My original point was that you shouldn't suggest something without a reason. Just saying "you should do this" doesn't help anyone. You're absolutely obviously right about other code that *could* break yours because you don't check with `hasOwnProperty`, but if you don't understand the other code and know when it's **needed**, you shouldn't use it

Comment: @MattBurland **Any** code can ruin anything. It's just as easy to override a method, like `hasOwnProperty` and end up breaking yours. If you're going to be paranoid about one thing, you should be paranoid about everything related. At some point, you have to stop "safeguarding" your own code and trust or use other code that wouldn't break it

Answer (score 3):

Remember that a `for in` loop in javascript returns an objects property key not the object the key refers to. Also use [`.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to avoid possibly looping over an objects prototype.

You would need to change it to:

```
for (var coord in myObj){
  if(myObj.hasOwnProperty[coord]){
    var coord = myObj[coord];
    for(var section in coord)
      if(coord.hasOwnProperty[section]){
        alert(coord[section]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```